# Polymer 1.x: Getting custom element to say HELLO WORLD in Plunker

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, plunker, iron-data-table, polymer-1.x

[In this Plunk, why won't the `x-foo` element render HELLO WORLD?](http://plnkr.co/edit/p7IE7v6DHLVnEggeO8PF?p=preview).

Given the more complex `content-el` seems to be importing an `iron-data-table` perfectly correctly. Am I overlooking something simple? Please answer with a working plunk.

http://plnkr.co/edit/p7IE7v6DHLVnEggeO8PF?p=preview

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

<dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
        <style></style>
        HELLO WORLD
    </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',

            });
        })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: [Based on accepted answer, here is a working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/sxRcb1RSMZJc0rqS6gbQ?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice the browser console displays:

> https://polygit.org/polymer/components/polymer/polymer.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
>
> https://polygit.org/polymer/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
>
> x-foo.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined

The browser cannot find the required imports for Polymer because your `<base>` URL has a malformed polygit configuration in `x-foo.html`:

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer/components/">
```

Expected [URL format](https://polygit.org/) for `polygit.org`:

```
<server-name>/[<configurations>/]components/<component>/<path>
```

where `<configurations>/` is:

```
<component>[+<org>]+<ver>|:<branch>|*
```

So your `<base>` URL should be any of the following:

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v1.7.0/components/">
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FHBpjdHmytYuKsDS9NnB?p=preview)